# Ubuntu 15.10 Stuck on black screen with blinking cursor after boot animation

Tags: boot, lightdm

I did the normal ubuntu upgrades, added these lines to startup applications-commands: `sudo aticonfig --px-igpu` and `sudo tlp start` on last working boot. These could be one of the causes but I am not sure.

I'm just able to boot into recovery mode and that doesn't connect automatically to my wifi even after enabling network so I can't install new packages from the internet.

I tried removing fglrx but it shows its not installed, but I am sure I have installed AMD drivers from official site and aticonfig command works even in recovery mode.

I am attaching the log of lightdm.

```
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.16.7, UID=0 PID=807
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-kde-plasma-kf5.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG:   [SeatDefaults] is now called [Seat:*], please update this configuration
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /usr/local/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration dirs from /etc/xdg/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.04s] DEBUG: Registered seat module unity
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
[+0.05s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
[+0.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+0.06s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+0.07s] DEBUG: Quitting Plymouth
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.09s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+0.09s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.09s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.09s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Launching process 817: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.10s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.10s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.50s] DEBUG: Loading users from org.freedesktop.Accounts
[+0.50s] DEBUG: User /org/freedesktop/Accounts/User1000 added
[+1.39s] DEBUG: Process 817 terminated with signal 6
[+1.39s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+1.39s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+1.39s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+1.39s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+1.39s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping; greeter display server failed to start
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+1.40s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1
```